# Gallery item is not updated After file downloading

Tags: java, android, image-gallery, android-gallery

I have one wallpaper application which have save image function. Its working fine but image downloaded from application is only showing after restart mobile. can some one please help me for solve that issue ?
my code for download image is like below.

```html
public class SaveTask extends AsyncTask<String , String , String>
   {
    
        private Context context;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String image_url;
        URL myFileUrl;
        String myFileUrl1;
        Bitmap bmImg = null;
        File file ;

        public SaveTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Image ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {  

                myFileUrl = new URL(args[0]);
                //myFileUrl1 = args[0];

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();   
                conn.setDoInput(true);   
                conn.connect();     
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {       
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
            try {       

                String path = myFileUrl.getPath();
                String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File (filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Hindi Picture/");
                dir.mkdirs();
                String fileName = idStr;
                file = new File(dir, fileName);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bmImg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(idStr))));
                fos.flush();    
                fos.close();
                


            }
            catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    }
            return null;   
        }


       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(SlideImageActivity.this, "Image Saved Succesfully Hindi Picture Folder/", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
      mInterstitial.show();
     }
           pDialog.dismiss();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the system to run a media scanner and only then the file will appear in the gallery. Which can be done as follows:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
              Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

OR

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
          new String[] { filepath.getAbsolutePath() }, null,
          new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
         // your code here
      }
 });
```

in your onPostExecute